# Why does this triple loop code have a running time of 1.5lnN * N^2

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis

[image: r]
Hi all, I'm currently going through the Princeton Algorithms course on coursera, and I'm having trouble understanding the answer to this quiz. I think I understand where the $\frac{1}{2} N^2$ term comes from, but I am completley lost on the $3 \ln N$ term. Unfortunatley this is the only solution.

Comment: The factor 3 comes from the fact that it is accessing three times the array $a$ in line 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider the outer two loops first. For a *fixed* value of $i$, the number of iterations of the middle loop is exactly $n-1 - (i+1) + 1 = n - i -1$.
Since $i$ ranges from $0$ to $n-1$ (in the outer loop), the *overall* number of iterations of the middle loop is:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (n - i -1) =
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.
$$

For each of those iterations we execute the inner loop for a certain number $x \in \mathbb{N}$ of iterations. Notice that $x$ only depends on $n$ and not on $i$ or $j$.
Before the first iteration, the value of $k$ is $1$, and it doubles after every iteration (i.e., before the next iteration starts). This means that after a generic number $h \in \mathbb{N}$ of iterations (i.e., just before the $(h+1)$-th iteration starts) the value of $k$ is $2^h$. Since the loop continues as long as $k = 2^h < n$, we are interested in the minimum value of $h$ for which the above inequality is not true. This is $x = \lceil \log n \rceil $ if $n \ge 1$ (where we used the fact that $h$ must be a non-negative integer) and $x = 0$ otherwise. Since you are interested in the asymptotic behavior of the algorithm, I will ignore this latter case.

Finally, notice that for each iteration of the inner loop, exactly $3$ array accesses are performed.

To summarize:

- We reach the inner loop $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ times;
- Each time we perform $\lceil \log n \rceil$ iterations;
- Each iteration causes $3$ array accesses.

The total number of array accesses is therefore:
$ \frac{3}{2}n(n-1) \lceil \log n \rceil  \sim \frac{3}{2}n^2 \log n$.